# How to load albumart of the song downloaded by other music apps

Tags: android, mediastore, audio-player, albumart, android-music-player

I am working on a Music Player.Using

```
MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

I can retrieve the information of music downloaded by other Music apps(**if sync to the local**).But I still can't get **the album artwork ** by the same way I 
get the artwork of local music -

```
 Uri artworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
 Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(artworkUri, albumId);
```

Since I already retrieve the music info , why can't I get the artwork by the same old way?It's sure that these songs has their albumart when other apps playing...
Ps: and what's the different about this Uri

```
"content://media/external/audio/media/" + songId + "/albumart"
```

Any suggestions/hints are all appreciated!